# Who would have been the optimal partner of Alia according to the Bene Gesserit?

Tags: dune

In Dune Messiah, Chapter 11, the Reverend Mother Gaius Helen Mohiam is negotiating with Paul. Near the end of the Chapter she looks at Alia and thinks:

> And again she looked at the sister. The optimum cross for this female Atreides had been lost, killed by Paul.

Who would this person have been?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Bene Gesserit plan was to breed the Kwisatz Haderach and at the time of Dune, they were 2 generations away (until the events of dune).

Lady Jessica was meant to bear a daughter with Leto Atreides but as we well know a son was born.  While Paul was a Kwisatz Haderach, he was not the planned Kwisatz Haderach as per the Bene Gesserit breeding program.

When Lady Jessica became pregnant again, with a female, the Bene Gesserit plan could still be salvaged via the breeding of Alia and Feyd-Rautha Harkonnen.

Paul destroyed that when he killed Feyd-Rautha Harkonnen

Comment: Why would it have been Feyd-Rautha? Was this their original plan for the breeding programme if Jessica would have gotten a daugther?

In my edition of "Dune" she thinks on page 522 when Feyd fights against Paul
"Two end products of this long and costly programme faced each other in a fight to the death that might easily claim both of them." This would support your theory that Feyd was a part of the breeding scheme.

Comment: the plan was the Jessica-Leto daughter to breed with Feyd.  Why Feyd particularly? who knows, the breeding program spanned 10,000 years. One thing to consider is Jessica's father is Baron Harkonnen so maybe there was something in that cross-breed

Comment: Isn't it also a problem that Alia is an "abomination"? Spice inflicted while in the womb? There could be no salvage from her. With Feyd's and Leto's death, the program was lost. But I think I recall hints at other unnamed programs?  Maybe just less successful, or further behind?

Comment: It shouldn't have been, the DNA is un-altered. The BG did start two other programs though, one LetaII took over.

Comment: It's not a DNA problem, but that her progeny would be abomination too.

Comment: Maybe the BG hoped that with early an intense training their KH would no succumb and also turn into an abomination.  Being able to test for has been part of the BG way, hence the test for humanity so at some point they must have run into issues with sisters not being able to control themselves. A small hope is still a hope vs no hope at all

Comment: Didn't Paul see something in Hasimir Fenring during (or really after) the duel with Feud? I always thought that meant that Fenring was also from one of the finer lines of the BG breeding program.

Comment: @Arthur Fenring was an ‘almost Kwisatz Haderach’ but he was incaple of reproduction.  He was a dead end of the program..

Comment: Of course the reason that Paul was the KH was because Jessica was secretly part-Harkonnen.  I assume that Mohiam hadn't figure this out yet, at this point?  (Also, if that was all it took, why hadn't they figured out that they needed to cross in the Harkonnens a little bit earlier?  Sloppy.)

Comment: oh they knew, that was the entire point of the breeding program. Mohiam berated Jessica for believing she would bear the KH, when in actual fact the reason she chose a son was because she loved Leto - the the BG considered arrogance over love for the actions of Jessica

Comment: Isn't it rather sketchy that a 10000 year program _ends_ with one death?  There were no alternatives?  What if the guy had gotten run over by a bus?  Oh, too bad, gonna take another 1500 years now?

Answer (score 12):

She's referring to Feyd-Rautha Harkonnen.

Near the beginning of the first book, Mohiam tells Jessica: "An Atreides daughter could've been wed to a Harkonnen heir and sealed the breach". In your quote she's reflecting that the match could still have been made, if Paul hadn't killed Feyd.